# Component not Re-rendering after change in state (React-Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering

I am new to React and Redux, I am trying out a "Todo" app, using react-redux. Its not complete. When I add a task, it is adding in the state and in UI, when I delete the component using a button, it gets deleted from the state, but the component utilizing it, is not re-rendered. The App.js file is given below.

Edit: This is the Github link of the app [GitHub Link](https://github.com/suresh-rsk/todo)

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Control from './Components/Control';
import ListItem from './Components/ListItem';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

function App() {

  let todo=useSelector((state)=>state.List);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <div className="box">
          <Control/>
          {
          (todo.length>0)?
          todo.map((i)=>{return(<ListItem key={i.heading} props={i}/>)})
          :<br/>
          }
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Either upload your code on sandbox or please share all component's code.

Comment: You will *at least* need to show your reducer and how you trigger that store change.

Comment: The most likely cause of this type of issue is a mutation of state in your reducer.

Comment: Hi @UmairRiaz I have added the Github link to the project.

Comment: @phry please find the code in the Github link provided

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes it was the cause and I just found out the solution. Thanks